# What has to be made that whenever new columns are made in a table in SWT , by default Listeners are created , not having to manually add them

Tags: java, swt

What has to be made that whenever new columns are made in a table in SWT , by default Listeners are created , not having to manually add them

Answer (score 1):

Which listeners do you have defined already for your TableColumn?

The short answer is no.  Every time you create a TableColumn, you must add all of the listeners that it needs.  You can have one listener (a move listener, for example) added to all of your TableColumns, but you have to add it every time you create a new one.